# Copy an image from a Word document into an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to copy a picture from a word document into a cell in Excel, but every time I try to paste the picture I get an "\".

Can someone help me please?

Is there a simple way to do this operation in VBA?

I use selection to search between two chapters (The selection works perfectly but the copy does not.)

My code is as follows:

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")
Dim r1 As Long


wrdApp.Selection.WholeStory
wrdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
With wrdApp.Selection.Find
     .Text = "ABCD"
     .Forward = True
     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
     .Format = False
     .MatchCase = False
     .MatchWholeWord = True
     .MatchWildcards = False
     .MatchSoundsLike = False
     .MatchAllWordForms = False
     .Execute
End With
r1 = wrdApp.Selection.Range.End

wrdApp.Selection.Find.Text = "BCDE"
If wrdApp.Selection.Find.Execute Then
    wrdApp.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
Else
    wrdApp.Selection.WholeStory
    wrdApp.Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End If
     
wrdDoc.Range(r1, wrdApp.Selection.Start).Select

With wrdApp.Selection
    MySheet.Range("B3").Value = .InlineShapes(1)
End With
```

Comment: How can you expect anyone to help without showing the code you are using? Please include that in your question.

Comment: As braX has said, we need your code. It would also be helpful to know your operating system and version of Office.

Comment: Sorry, please see the new update as soon as possible
Thank you for your alert.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.

1. The variable `MySheet` isn't declared and doesn't point to anything.
   As a result your code doesn't compile.
2. Although your question mentions using copy and paste your code
   doesn't copy or paste anything.
3. The `.Value` of a cell cannot be a picture.
4. When using VBA, whether in Excel, PowerPoint or Word, it is best to
   avoid using the `Selection` object and use `Range` instead.

   ```
   Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
   Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   wrdApp.Visible = True

   Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\test.docx")

   Dim r1 As Word.Range
   Set r1 = ActiveDocument.Range

   With wrdDoc.Range
       With .Find
           .ClearFormatting
           .Replacement.ClearFormatting
           .Text = "ABCD"
           .Format = False
           .Forward = True
           .Wrap = wdFindStop
           .MatchWildcards = False
       End With
       If .Find.Execute Then r1.Start = .End

       .Find.Text = "BCDE"
       If .Find.Execute Then r1.End = .Start
   End With

   r1.InlineShapes(1).Range.Copy

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B3").PasteSpecial

   wrdDoc.Close False
   wrdApp.Quit
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
This really works, however I am having a rather weird problem with some files this code gives me the error  Run-time error 1004: "Aplication-defined  or object-defined error".
Unfortunately I can't send you any examples of the file, as they are completely confidential. Can you please help me?

Comment: @FranciscoSilva - you need to do further analysis and identify exactly what the circumstances are that give you the error. Then you can research the issue and if you can't find a solution ask another question on SO.

Comment: The problem happens in PasteSpecial method.
I cannot understand why, because in "simpler" files I can copy the image without any problem. I tested copying the same image in all tests

Comment: @FranciscoSilva - there simply isn't enough information to give a proper answer. I don't have the files you are working with and don't know how you are using the code. The only thing that comes to mind is that if you are using this code in a loop there could be timing issues with the clipboard. Adding `DoEvents` between copying and pasting may help, but really, as I said earlier, you should make this a separate question and provide all relevant information.